# Same footer on all multisites blogs

Tags: theme-development, multisite

There is any way of using the main site footer (blog id =1) on all the network sites.
I want to have the same footer in all the network.
On the main site i got a theme and the child sites created by users got another theme.

**Basically i want to use the same footer on both themes but manage all the widgets from just the main site.**

Its possible to do this using switch_to_blog or something similar?

UPDATE:
I tried but no luck:

```
<?php
    global $switched;
    switch_to_blog(1);

     get_footer(); 

restore_current_blog();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, using the same `footer.php` file for multiple themes would be problematic, as different themes use different elements which need to be closed in this file.

A better way would be to create a custom function that you call in every `footer.php` file. Such a function would be best placed in a file in `wp-content/mu-plugins` so it is loaded first for every site:

```
function my_custom_footer() {
    echo 'Copyright &copy ' . date('Y') .' ACME Studios Inc.';
}
```

And then call the function in a theme's `footer.php` file:

```
my_custom_footer();
```

Another method instead of calling the same function in **every theme** would be to to hook into the `wp_footer` action (which should be called in every theme):

```
function my_custom_footer() {
    echo 'Copyright &copy ' . date('Y') .' ACME Studios Inc.';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_custom_footer' );
```

Dropping this latest snippet into a file in `wp_content/mu-plugins` will make the text appear in the footer of every theme! If you want to manually position or style the text, you can do so by locating the call to `wp_footer()` in a theme's `footer.php` file and wrapping it in HTML elements.

If you'd prefer to leave `wp_footer()` for hidden HTML content such as footer scripts, you can call your own action in `footer.php` and then hook into it whereever you like:

In `footer.php`:

```
do_action( 'wpse_footer_content' );
```

In a mu-plugin:

```
add_action( 'wpse_footer_content', function () { ?>

    content goes here

<?php } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just use switch_to_blog and restore_current_blog on either end of the footer, then code your footer as if you were on your main blog between those functions.

Comment: it doesnt work, widgets are not showing.

Comment: Make sure you're properly calling switch_to_blog() with the right blog id in the function, and dump a few queries to double check that you're on the right blog.